# Apache beam IOException in decoder

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a simple pipeline that reads from Kafka by KafkaIO reader and transforms next into pipeline. In the end, it writes down to GCP in avro format. So when I run the pipeline in DataFlow it works perfectly but when the runner is DirectRunner it reads all data from topics and throws the exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Forbidden IOException when reading from InputStream
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromSafeStream(CoderUtils.java:118)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:98)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:92)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.clone(CoderUtils.java:141)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.CloningBundleFactory$CloningBundle.add(CloningBundleFactory.java:84)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.GroupAlsoByWindowEvaluatorFactory$OutputWindowedValueToBundle.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowEvaluatorFactory.java:251)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.GroupAlsoByWindowEvaluatorFactory$OutputWindowedValueToBundle.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowEvaluatorFactory.java:237)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1057)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:438)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:125)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTimers(ReduceFnRunner.java:768)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.GroupAlsoByWindowEvaluatorFactory$GroupAlsoByWindowEvaluator.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowEvaluatorFactory.java:185)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.processElements(DirectTransformExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.run(DirectTransformExecutor.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.VarInt.decodeLong(VarInt.java:73)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.IterableLikeCoder.decode(IterableLikeCoder.java:136)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.IterableLikeCoder.decode(IterableLikeCoder.java:60)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.decode(Coder.java:159)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder.decode(KvCoder.java:82)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder.decode(KvCoder.java:36)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromSafeStream(CoderUtils.java:115)
    ... 19 more
```

I use custom serializator and deserializator for reading avro and getting paylod.

**Kafka Reader**

```
  private PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<KV<String, AvroGenericRecord>>> createKafkaRead(Map<String, Object> configUpdates) {
        return KafkaIO.<String, AvroGenericRecord>read()
                .withBootstrapServers(bootstrapServers)
                .withConsumerConfigUpdates(configUpdates)
                .withTopics(inputTopics)
                .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                .withValueDeserializerAndCoder(BeamKafkaAvroGenericDeserializer.class, AvroGenericCoder.of(serDeConfig()))
                .withMaxNumRecords(maxNumRecords)
                .commitOffsetsInFinalize()
                .withoutMetadata();
    }
```

**AvroGenericCoder**

```
public class AvroGenericCoder extends CustomCoder<AvroGenericRecord> {
    private final Map<String, Object> config;
    private transient BeamKafkaAvroGenericDeserializer deserializer;
    private transient BeamKafkaAvroGenericSerializer serializer;

    public static AvroGenericCoder of(Map<String, Object> config) {
        return new AvroGenericCoder(config);
    }

    protected AvroGenericCoder(Map<String, Object> config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    private BeamKafkaAvroGenericDeserializer getDeserializer() {
        if (deserializer == null) {
            BeamKafkaAvroGenericDeserializer d = new BeamKafkaAvroGenericDeserializer();
            d.configure(config, false);
            deserializer = d;
        }
        return deserializer;
    }

    private BeamKafkaAvroGenericSerializer getSerializer() {
        if (serializer == null) {
            serializer = new BeamKafkaAvroGenericSerializer();
        }
        return serializer;
    }

    @Override
    public void encode(AvroGenericRecord record, OutputStream outStream) {
        getSerializer().serialize(record, outStream);
    }

    @Override
    public AvroGenericRecord decode(InputStream inStream) {
        try {
            return getDeserializer().deserialize(null, IOUtils.toByteArray(inStream));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error translating into bytes ", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void verifyDeterministic() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object structuralValue(AvroGenericRecord value) {
        return super.structuralValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);
    }
}
```

This is **main pipeline**

```
PCollection<AvroGenericRecord> records = p.apply(readKafkaTr)
                .apply(Window.<AvroGenericRecord>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(options.getWindowInMinutes())))
                        .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                                .withEarlyFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                                        .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(options.getWindowInMinutes())))
                                .withLateFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(options.getElementsCountToWaitAfterWatermark())))
                        .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardDays(options.getAfterWatermarkInDays()))
                        .discardingFiredPanes()
                );

        records.apply(Filter.by((ProcessFunction<AvroGenericRecord, Boolean>) Objects::nonNull))
                .apply(new WriteAvroFilesTr(options.getBasePath(), options.getNumberOfShards()));
```

Comment: Could you post a code snippet of your pipeline here, please?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanenko sure

Comment: @AlexeyRomanenko could you please explain how it is possible that it works well on DataFlow but when I run with DirectRunner it throws the exception?

Comment: One possible difference between the runners is that DirectRunner will materialize every collection (i.e. the coder will *definitely* be used), while DataflowRunner will fuse transformations.  The stack trace resembles a coder issue...

Comment: @RyanSkraba Yes, it definitely because of a coder. But this is not my custom coder.

Comment: @Dave similar issue here, did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think @RyanSkraba is right - DirectRunner does many things that not all other runners do (because initial goal of DirectRunner was to be used for testing, so it performs many additional checks comparing to other runners).

Btw, why would not use Beam `AvroCoder` in this case? Simple example how to use it with `KafkaIO`: 
https://github.com/aromanenko-dev/beam-issues/blob/master/kafka-io/src/main/java/KafkaAvro.java

Comment: Thanks for the example! Our streaming is much difficult than it would seem. In our case, we have integration with Hortonworks Schema registry and during serialization/deserialization we need to get a schema and metadata for a payload. So we can't use default AvroCoder. We have custom coder which use custom deserializator and serializator.

Comment: I would say that our pipeline is a fork from https://github.com/AzimoLabs/kafka-to-avro-writer and tuned for our use cases.